# select COUNT and then condition SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a condition which based on my Count result, it should skip or include a join in my query,to make short the story,how to implement such a thing in SQL:

```
select count(names) as rslt
if(rslt)>0 then
select......join tables
else
Select...
```

as you see I want to say if the count is >0 then do the join otherwise it should skip then join and go to the next line,how should I achieve this?

Comment: put it into a variable first

Comment: @dbajtr can you make an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if a resulting query returns any row (`>0`) then you should use an `IF` with an `EXISTS` rather than using `COUNT`. `EXISTS` will make the SQL engine stop running once it finds at least 1 row, while `COUNT` will force to actually count all records.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM YourTable WHERE names IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN

    SELECT
        YourColumn
    FROM
        Table1
        INNER JOIN Table2 ON --...

END
ELSE
BEGIN

    SELECT
        YourColumn
    FROM
        Table1

END
```

If on the other hand you need to check a specific amount, then you will have to `COUNT` and assign to variable.

```
DECLARE @CountTotal INT = (SELECT COUNT(names) FROM YourTable)

IF @CountTotal > 100
BEGIN

    SELECT
        YourColumn
    FROM
        Table1
        INNER JOIN Table2 ON --...

END
ELSE
BEGIN

    SELECT
        YourColumn
    FROM
        Table1

END
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @Name INT

SELECT
    @Name = COUNT(names)
FROM Table

IF @Name > 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Do somthing'
END
ELSE
    PRINT 'Do something else'
END
```

Just change the `PRINT` statements to your query logic

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @reslt integer     
 @reslt = select count(names)
    if @reslt >0 then
    select......join tables
```

You need to put it in a variable and then call it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use dynamic query like below:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT *
  FROM T1 ' + CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(names) FROM  table1) > 0 THEN + 
  ' INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.Id = T2.Id '  ELSE  '' END

PRINT @SQL

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CASE function, something like this :

```
Select count(CustomerID),
CASE
WHEN count(CustomerID) > 30 THEN "The quantity is greater than 30"
WHEN count(CustomerID) = 30 THEN "The quantity is 30"
ELSE "The quantity is something else"
END
FROM Customers;
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can try below method as well.

```
 if((select count(Name) from tableName)>0)
 begin
    select 1
 end 
 else
 begin
    select 2
 end
```

No need to use one temp variable to store the count .